# Attempt to accept pages blocked by URL filtering control!

Tags: support

Today when I went to log into one of the Stack Exchange Websites (Anime and Manga) I got the following message.

> Attempt to Accept Pages Blocked by URL Filtering Control!!!!
>
> You have tried to access the web site that is not allowed by the URL Filtering Control.
>
> To access the website, please login the router and change the URL Filter configuration.

Now on Friday the 11th of December when I went onto Stack Overflow I was getting a red message bar saying a JavaScript file was blocked and after looking up the offending file I found that the Ajax call to Google APIs for the jQuery library was giving the exact same message. However, after a while it seemed to fix itself.

So I am wondering: What is going on?

Comment: See the part [what else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) to have an idea of what needs to be reachable from your network.

Answer (score 6):

There's some software between you and the internet which is blocking these URLs.

If you are browsing from work or college it's highly likely that your employer or college administrators don't want you looking at "inappropriate" sites during the time you are supposed to be working or studying.

Try again from your home connection - unless it's your ISP that doing the blocking of course.

Comment: I would bet is a router url filtering.